# ASP.NET - Local & Production Servers - Control ID Difference

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html

Hi All I am having this problem. Locally everything is working fine. Once I upload the published version on production the IDs of all elements will have a different prefix.

I know that the prefix is caused by using master pages, but why it is different from local to production?

See Image

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100708-pg6exce3jd6f3dga2huse1u7pi.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100708-pg6exce3jd6f3dga2huse1u7pi.jpg)

Comment: What version of IIS is on production? What version is on "local"?

Comment: @David Bonnici - I am not asking about what version of .NET. I am asking about the actual IIS webserver (5.1, 6.0, 7.0 or 7.5).

Comment: Both on production and local?

Comment: Compare your 2 web.config, and search for possible TagPrefix extra options.

Comment: They are both the same. The problem that I am noticing is this. This occurs ONLY when the application is on a virtual directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Matt-dot-net, dont use hardcoded client-side control ids.

However, check your dev/production web.configs for xhtmlConformance mode="Legacy" (or something similar), if only one of your configs has this set then it may account for you having different ids on dev and production .

Cheers Tigger

Answer (score 1):

This happens.  The lesson to be learned is don't rely on "hardcoded" client-side control ids.  That's why asp.net gives you the Control.ClientID property.  Use it in place of your hard-coded value.